# Why does changing the icon of a jQuery UI Button break my link in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I am trying to change the icon of a button as soon as it was used.
The code is pretty simple:

```
<a id='just-a-link' target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Google</a>

jQuery('#just-a-link').button().bind('click', function() {

    var icons = jQuery(this).button("option", "icons");
    icons.primary = 'ui-icon-plus';

    jQuery(this).button("option", "icons", icons);

});
```

However Internet Explorer the link does not get fired.
So **clicking** on the link **does change the icon but does not open the page**.

What do you suggest to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/YnwnU/

In the fiddle you can see that `jQuery(this).button("option", "icons", icons);` causes the bug as the second button does open the link.

Comment: it might be worth noting that this works fine in other browser, so looks like an IE-specific bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright well after looking at it some more, it looks like since you are calling `.button()` inside of an already established `.button()` call, it happens to be killing -href- or whatever eventHandlers were already set on it. (In this case opening a new window & link.

```
jQuery('#just-a-link').button().bind('click', function() {
    var icons = jQuery(this).button("option", "icons");
    icons.primary = 'ui-icon-plus';

    // Adding this makes it work in IE for at least the code you currently have
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

It looks more to me like you are trying to simply add an icon to all external links, and open them in a new window. Why not just do *this* instead?

```
var icons = jQuery(this).button("option", "icons");
    icons.primary = 'ui-icon-plus';

jQuery('a[target="_blank"]').button().button("option", "icons", icons);
```

No need for binding a click... just setting all anchors with `target="_blank"` to button & giving them the Icon. This also makes it work automatically in IE and other browsers. Give it a go.

[updated jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YnwnU/7/)

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question why it would be needed for IE, but not for others... but it of course does to the one "what to do about it" :)

Comment: Updated! Think it's just because the .button() is called again inside of itself

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Some users have a slow connection and it takes some seconds to load the application. So they click multiple times on the button. To prevent this we disable the button and add a spinner image ;) - The `target=_blank` was just easier to debug.